# how to create parent/child associations in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a Employee and their dependents model defined in sequlieze. I have an employeeId foreign key column defined in the dependent table ( see my model class below) . but when i try to execute following command

```
  models.Employee.findOne({where: { id: Number(id) }, include: [{ model: models.Dependent }]});
```

i get an error -> EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Dependent is not associated to Employee!

*isn't specifying a foreign key in the dependent model , enough?*

Employee model

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Employee = sequelize.define('Employee ', {
    id : {
           type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
           allowNull: false, 
           autoIncrement:true,
           primaryKey:true
        },
   Name : { ... }
```

Dependent model

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Dependent = sequelize.define('Dependent', {
    id : {
           type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
           allowNull: false, 
           autoIncrement:true,
           primaryKey:true
        },
    EmployeeId : {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: true,
        references : {
            model : 'Employee ',
            key:'id'
        }
    },
    Name : { ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*isn't specifying a foreign key in the dependent model, enough?*

No, it's **NOT** enough if you want to use **[Eager Loading](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html)** of sequelize.

You need to create sequelize associations for these models(`Employee` and `Dependent` for your case) in pairs, see [Why associations are defined in pairs?](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#why-associations-are-defined-in-pairs-)

The `references` option in the model only creates an FK relationship between `Dependent` and `Employee` tables in the database(relationship for db level). Does not include associations of sequelize model(relationship for application level). When to use? see [Enforcing a foreign key reference without constraints](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/constraints-and-circularities.html#enforcing-a-foreign-key-reference-without-constraints)

Employee has many dependents and dependent belongs to one Employee. So you need to create [One-To-Many relationships](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#one-to-many-relationships).

```js
Employee.hasMany(Dependent);
Dependent.belongsTo(Employee);
```

create associations like above will create FK reference for tables implicitly.

Execution results:

```
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "employees" ("id"   SERIAL , "name" VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "dependents" ("id"   SERIAL , "name" VARCHAR(255), "EmployeeId" INTEGER REFERENCES "employees" ("id") ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
```